# Apple Watch app submitting

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm submiting support for Apple Watch for my app. App on Watch simulator works fine but my app is rejected due to following reason:

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on Apple
>   Watch. Specifically, your app is failing to launch on the Apple Watch
>   device.

This is weird since my app works fine with watch simulator. So my question is should watch binary be in embedded binaries in main iOS app?

[Screenshot](http://image.prntscr.com/image/58829afcf3fe4b94b3508969abbfd8c6.png) of my current settings

Answer (score 1):

No, in watchOS 2, the WatchKit extension should ***not*** be an embedded binary of the iOS app. It runs on the watch itself, not on the host device.

The extension ***is*** an embedded binary of the watchOS app. The iOS app embeds the watch app, and [the watch app embeds its extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html).

**About the simulator:**

Testing on the simulator doesn't guarantee that the app will also work on an actual device. You should also test on the real hardware device [to catch issues which wouldn't be revealed by the simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH5-SW27).

> Simulator is designed to assist you in designing, rapidly prototyping, and testing your app, but **it should never serve as your sole platform for testing**. One reason is that not all apps are available in the simulator. For example, the Camera app is available only on hardware devices and cannot be replicated in the simulator.
>
> In addition, **not all bugs and performance problems can be caught through testing in Simulator alone**.

Since your computer has a faster CPU and more memory than the actual watch, it's very possible for your app to perform better on the simulator, but perform poorly or fail on an actual device.

Comment: Is bitcode required for watch apps? I would test my app on actual watch but unfortunately I don't own one.

Comment: That sounds like a completely unrelated question.  You should research it first before asking a new question, as you'll likely find existing answers here on SO :) As for not owning a watch, submitting an app to the App Store is not the way to get people to test it for you.  Use testflight and work out these issues before you submit an app, to avoid running into more rejections down the road.